# warning: suggest parentheses around operand of '!' or change '&' to '&&' or '!' to '~'

Tags: c

What is wrong with this code?

```
if ( (global_controller.settings->identity_settings.jjj != xxx) &&
     (!global_controller.settings->electric_settings.ccc & yyy))
```

When I compile it is like if the second condition doesn't exist.

Comment: Have you tried doing what the warning is telling you?

Comment: You are doing logical NOT but bitwise AND

Comment: Think about the operator precedence in an expression of the form `! a & b`.

Comment: @stark: I think that part is intentional, it appears to be testing a bit.

Comment: What is `~a&b`? Maybe `(~a)&b`, maybe `~(a&b)`. Do you know for sure without looking it up (or experimenting)? On the other hand, there is absolutely no question with using `(~a)&b` or `~(a&b)`

Comment: @NateEldredge: The bitwise AND may be intentional, but the logical NOT? It's certainly an odd combination.

Comment: Whether intentional or not, it is still confusing to mix them.

Comment: My assumption is that it's supposed to be true if the bit is not set.  So it's written as `! bits & mask` but should be `!(bits & mask)`.  The latter wouldn't be confusing at all, in my opinion.

Comment: @NateEldredge: That's certainly one possibility. I don't think we know enough from the question what the actual intent is.

Comment: Explain in plain english what this conditon should do: `(!global_controller.settings->electric_settings.retracks & RETRACKING_BY_RECHARGE))` then we can help.

Comment: @Johnny now you see what's wrong with this code: we discussed it for more than 5 minutes, and don't know if it does what you intended. Just do as the compiler suggests, and clarify your intentions by picking one of the options it provided.

Comment: "When I compile it is like if the second condition doesn't exist." - that sounds like the code does behave differently from what you expected - could you please tell us what you intended to do (expected inputs and expected outcome)?

Comment: Like the second condition does not exist? If the first one is `false` then the second won't be examined.

Comment: Given the precedence of `!` and `&`, the compiler suggests you might have made a mistake and should use explicit parentheses to confirm the expression.

This warning is usually a lifesaver and it is very likely you meant this instead:

`if ( (global_controller.settings->identity_settings.jjj != xxx) &&
     !(global_controller.settings->electric_settings.ccc & yyy))`.
If `yyy` is an even constant, the original expression is always false as `!global_controller.settings->electric_settings.ccc` is either 0 or 1, so `(!global_controller.settings->electric_settings.ccc & yyy)` is always `0`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really intended to use a bitwise AND, then probably you meant by:

```
if ( (global_controller.settings->identity_settings.index_in_installation != SETTINGS_UNSET_SOLARFIGHTER_ID) && \
     !(global_controller.settings->electric_settings.retracks & RETRACKING_BY_RECHARGE))
____^^^____
```

Notice the syntax carefully:

```
if ((condition_1) && !(condition2))
```

Whereas you did:

```
(!global_controller.settings->electric_settings.retracks & RETRACKING_BY_RECHARGE))
^^^_____
```

**You makes two separated conditions when using `!` under parenthesis scope:**

```
if ((condition_1) && (!condition2_1 & condition2_2))
```

Comment: Maybe he wants this, but can we be sure?

Comment: @Jabberwocky the OP hasn't provided any better idea except the compiler warning to the code. Because mixing the conditions `(!abc & def)` doesn't makes sense, rather `!(abc & def)` does, I guess.